# Grails dataBinding not working on default marshalled grails date

Tags: date, grails, binding

It seems that Grails by default is providing a date marshalled in JSON as "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" (e.g: Sat Jan 05 00:02:00 CET 2019)

If this (string) date is used in a domain creation activity (create an instance of the same domain class with this string-date as the date), Grails will not recognize it by default (although I think it should logically accept it).

Pooblem is that the Data Format "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" is not recognized in the

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = [
        'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy',
        'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',
        'dd/MM/yyyy',
        'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
        'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S',
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'",
        'dd.mm.yyyy',
        'MMddyyyy'
]
```

or in the @BindingFormat as well.
It looked like, to parse the 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy', the locale is also needed.
Something like:

```
 def dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
 SimpleDateFormat smpDF= new SimpleDateFormat( dateFormat, Locale.UK );
```

Is there a way to pass the locate so grails binds this date as it is from the string?

Update: This is Grails 3.3.9

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown 3.3.9